# How to bind view to viewmodel instantiated with parameters?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

In my project I need to do something like this:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(parameters);
var view = new MyView();
// bind view to viewModel
view.Show();
```

`MyView` inherits `Window`.

Design implies that `MyView` shouldn't be aware of `parameters` and just represent 
properties of `MyViewModel`.

How should I implement this binding?

I got a suggestions that I can use `IViewFor` interface from ReactiveUI but I can't find any example of how to implement this solution.

Comment: The view binds to properties of its `DataContext`. You need to set the `DataContext` property of the view to your view model but the bindings to the properties of the view model should be set up in the view itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding root of a view is its `DataContext`, so you need to assign `viewModel` to it:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(parameters);
var view = new MyView();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
view.Show();
```